# Fastest way to apply function along axes

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, tensor

In a time-critical code fragment, I need to apply a function along different axes of a tensor and sum results. A peculiar feature is that the number of axes of the tensor (`ns_test`) can be large. I came up with two implementations, where I move the current axis (`moveaxis`) to either zeroth (`h_zero`) or last (`h_last`) position, apply the function, and move the axis back. I am not sure it is the best way.

```
import numpy as np
import time

def h_last(state, km, ns):
    new_state = np.zeros_like(state)
    for i in range(ns):
        a = np.moveaxis(state, i+1, -1).copy()
        for k in range(km):
            a[..., k] = (k+0.5) * a[..., k]
        new_state += np.moveaxis(a, -1, i+1)
    return new_state

def h_zero(state, km, ns):
    new_state = np.zeros_like(state)
    for i in range(ns):
        a = np.moveaxis(state, i+1, 0).copy()
        for k in range(km):
            a[k, ...] = (k+0.5) * a[k, ...]
        new_state += np.moveaxis(a, 0, i+1)
    return new_state

# ==================== init ============================
km_test  = 4        
ns_test = 7
nreps = 100
dims = tuple([ns_test] + [km_test] * ns_test)    
y= np.random.rand(*dims)
    
# =================== first run =============================
tic = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(nreps):
    yy = h_last(y, km_test, ns_test)
toc = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Run time h_last {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds")

# =================== second run =============================
tic = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(nreps):
    yyy = h_zero(y, km_test, ns_test)
toc = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Run time h_zero {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds")

print(np.linalg.norm(yy-yy))
```

I am surprised a bit that the zeroth axis performs better (I thought python internally uses the C-order for storage). But my main question is how to further speed up the code? I looked into `apply_along_axis`, but this seems to be very slow.

Comment: Why are your copying the `moveaxis` result? Isn't the whole point of `moveaxis` is to be fast because it is just a view?

Comment: @chrslg Because I modify `a` in place in this line `a[..., k] = (k+0.5) * a[..., k]` and because I do not want to destroy  the `state` by this operation.

Comment: Yes, I get that. But that makes the whole thing quite slow. Because you copy for each axis. Maybe you should copy `state` and work in place as long as possible.

Comment: @chrslg I thought about that but could not come up with an efficient solution.

Comment: Also, I find strange your `np.moveaxis(state, i+1, -1)`. What happens when `i` is `ns-1`. It should fail, shouldn't it? (you can't move the nth axis if there are n axes, from the 0th to the n-1th).

Comment: As for the performance issue, it depends on the size of your data, on the performance difference you see, etc. But understand that the reason why "C order" or not may matter, is because of low level consideration, namely cache memory. If you process data at memory address 0, then 1, then 2, then 3, ... the data are very likely to be already in cache. When if you process data at memory address 0, address 10000000, address 20000000, address 30000000, ... then CPU may need to retrieve a new page in the cache each time. But that doesn't matter for small array that fit all in cache.

Comment: That means that when you have a "normal" array, `arr[i,j]`, (I stick to 2D case for that explanation), it is better if computation are done in order `arr[0,0], arr[0,1], arr[0,2],..., arr[0,n-1], arr[1,0], arr[1,1], ..., arr[n-1, n-1]`.

Comment: Because that is also the order of the data in memory (in C order). So computation, cache-wise, is faster. But that is for "normal" array. Your `a` is not a normal array. It is a view. So it doesn't matter what axis you pretend to be iterating with variable `k` (the first one for `zero` version, the last one for the other), what you are iterating in reality is the ith axis. From a performance point of view, it is the ith axis. So it is faster when `i` is `ns-1`, slower when `i` is `0`.

Comment: Except maybe, because of the copy I've mentioned before. But it doesn't matter, because of my 2nd remark:

Comment: The real operation you are doing here, performance-wise, is not the iteration of k along the first (or the last axis). It is the operation `a[k,...] = ...` on a whole hyperplan. That operation is done by numpy. It iterates the whole "hyperplan" of data, in the optimal way (that is what numpy does). So, in C order. The least important iteration here is the more global one. That is precisely the one you seem to worry about.

Comment: @chrslg I tried bigger arrays that do not fit the cache (e.g. `km_test  = 3     
ns_test = 11`). The conclusion is the same.

Comment: Even more, if you think about it, because of the `copy` , in the first `a[k,...]` is really an operation made on a subset taken in the first axis. And `a[...,k]` in the last. So numpy operation `a[k,...]` is made on a subarray whose elements are adjacents in memory (because of the copy), while operation `a[...,k]` is made on subarray whose elements are separated by a not so small stride (stride of axis -2).

Comment: So, in short, the operation `a[k,...] *= ` is faster than operation `a[...,k] *= `, from this "C order / cache" perspective. Which is what you see, I think. If I summarize all my rant on this performance issue: if you weren't working on copies of `move_axis` result, then, it wouldn't matter at all what is the fake axis position you use. But since you are, it is quite normal that `zero` is better that `last`, since what matters is that the innermost index of a loop is the last axis (in C order). The the innermost index of the loop here occurs in the implicity loop of numpy `a[k, ...] *= ...`

Comment: `apply_along_axis` does something different - it iterates on all dimensions except the selected one, passing the selected 1d array to your function.  Interestingly it does permute the dimensions so the selected one is at one end, not for speed but for coding convenience.  Even so it doesn't improve performance (compared to a more direct nested iteration).

Comment: Whether `arr[k,...]` is faster or slower than `arr[...k]` gets into implementation details of memory, paging, caching etc, especially if the array is large.  The best choice is to avoid the iteration entirely.  I suspect that's possible with this simple test case, but may not be for your real world needs.

Comment: @hpaulj `apply_along_axis` does exactly the same. I have one more implementation which provides identical results but is much slower (therefore not even shown here). By the way, my simple test case is my real-world case. So if you know how to "avoid iteration entirely" I would be really curious to see.

Comment: Anyway, `apply_along_axis` is not made for performance. As for "how to avoid iteration entirely", it would be easier if we understood what you are trying to do. As far as I can tell, you are multiplying each element `a[i1,i2,i3,i4,...,in]` by Π(ik+½), that it by `(i1+0.5)*(i2+0.5)+...+(in+0.5)`. Is that the case?

Comment: @chrslg No, this is not the case. I loop over dimensions, multiply the tensor along the current dimension `i` with an index-dependent number `k+0.5` (k runs over this dimension),  and finally, sum up rescaled tensors.

Comment: Sorry, I was focusing on the `k` iteration, and ignoring the `i` one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments `moveaxis` is fast. It is just a view. So it is an interesting method to work when you have so many axes that you need a loop to iterate axis number and perform an operation on a given axis.

What slows down your computation is the many copies you make of your array along the way. Plus, as said in comments, it is also this copy that makes the version with last axis being slightly slower, because of "memory cache, and C order" considerations. I won't develop here what I said in comments, because it is quite accessory (we are talking 20% performance lost. Not negligible, but really nothing compare to your real problem)

So one way to do the operation you described faster is to avoid these copies

For example, here is a code that, roughly use the same tricks as you do (using `moveaxis`)

```py
tic = time.perf_counter()
kh=np.arange(0.5, km_test).reshape([1]*ns_test+[-1])

Y=np.zeros_like(y)
for i in range(ns_test):
    Y += y*np.moveaxis(kh, -1, i+1)
toc = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Run time arange {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds")

print(np.linalg.norm(yy-Y)) # Note that in your code you compare yy with yy. You probably meant yyy for one of the two yy.
```

Result on my PC

```
Run time h_last 1.2403 seconds
Run time h_zero 0.9995 seconds
Run time arange 0.0061 seconds
0.0
```

So result is the same.
But computation is approx. 2 times faster.

Yet, I use `moveaxis` as often as you do. On a smaller array, sure, since I've chose to use it only on the `arange` array. Move `moveaxis` cost is proportional to the number of axes, not the size of the data (it is just some play with strides and things like that. No data is moved. That's the whole point). Also, because of this `arange` I avoid one for loop. But it is probably not what explain most of the performance ratio. since that is an outer for loop (the important ones performance-wise, are the inner one, inside numpy `*` operation). So, what remains to explain the performance ratio, is the copy, I would say.

Note, for example, that if I do this

```
Y += np.moveaxis(np.moveaxis(y, i+1, -1)*kh, -1, i+1)
```

(that is moving axis of y instead of moving axis of kh. Which forces me to move the axis back before using the result, as you did) instead of my previous `Y+=...` line, it is also the same result, and the same kind of performance, while being even closer to your method. `moveaxis` costs nothing, roughly. So my choice of moving axis of `kh` is clearer for my taste, but is not what makes performance difference.

Comment: I perform a series of 100 runs. Therefore, your method is 1.5-2 times faster.  Here are my timings `Run time h_last 1.1713 seconds`, `Run time h_zero 0.8519 seconds`, `Run time h_chrslg 0.5479 seconds`. But it is indisputable that your method is faster.  The  vectorized `*` operation is obviously very fast. The implicit creation of factor array in `y*np.moveaxis(kh, -1, i+1)` is also faster than `moveaxis`on the whole thing.

Comment: It should be way faster than that tho. On your own code, I get 0.0061 secs to run what took 1 sec before.  Are the runs you mentioned on the same data (at least same shapes)?

Comment: Note that the bigger the data (km) for the same dimension (ns), the less important is the vectorization part. Because for small km, the inner part of your `k` loop (that is the pure numpy operation `a[k,...] = ...`) doesn't take lot of  time, so it matters that the outer loop (for k) is slow. But the bigger `km` the bigger the ratio between the number of operation in the numpy operation (O(km^ns)) and the number of operations for the loop itself (O(km)), and therefore, the less important become that O(km).

Comment: I double-check, everything seems consistent. Either my computer is very slow or yours is very fast.  I have `for i in range(nreps):` between `tic` and `toc`.

Comment: In other words, it is as if the numpy operation costs km^ns, and the outer for loop (that I avoid) costs 100000*km (so still O(km), but slow, because pure python). For small `km` that means that avoiding the 100000km still worth it. But for bigger km, even with that 100000 factor, it becomes negligible beform the km^ns part.

Comment: So, said otherwise, for bigger km (or bigger ns also. Bigger km^(ns-1) to be accurate), my initial bet (it is the `.copy()` that cost the more, not the vectorization) is truer and truer. Hence, maybe the factor 2-3 you find, which match what I attributed to copy. Again, that is true only if your runs are for bigger km or ns than your example. Otherwise, it is quite strange

Comment: FYI, my computer is really slow.

Comment: Ho, very simple answer to that (but not the one I expected): just now, I see that your timings are for `nreps` runs :D. Mine were for just one.

Comment: Nice analysis! I learned something new.  Your solution is quite unexpected.

Comment: And one consequence of that, is that, now that I do timings of nrep iteration, I confirm not only your timings (gain of factor 2), but also the fact that it is just the `.copy`, not really the vectorized for loop, that change thing (except that I don't know how to avoid the copy without that vectorized version).  This time, if I take my solution, and just add `.copy()` after `y` like this: `Y += y.copy()*np.moveaxis(kh, -1, i+1)` I get the same timings as your solution. So the gain factor is just the removal of `.copy()`. The vectorization here is just the mean to be able to remove it.

Comment: I fully agree with your analysis!

Comment: Hi, I would like to accept your answer, but it contains factually incorrect information about the 150-200 speedup. As I remarked above, the speedup is 1.5 to 2 times. Please, edit your answer and I would be glad to accept it. Very useful idea indeed.